# How do I connect this discord.js bot to uptimerobot.com?

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord, discord.js, glitch-framework

https://github.com/jDUUDEf/wubb2.0

I have other bots on Heroku and glitch.com that work fine with uptimerobot, but for some reason this one doesnt work on either. what do I do to make uptime robot ping this and keep it up on heroku or glitch (preferably glitch).

Comment: Just fyi your Url is 404.

Answer (score 1):

After making an account, here are the things you do.

1) Have the bot's code on glitch

2) Click 'Add new monitor'

3) Click 'Monitor Type' and select http(s)

4) Go back to your glitch project, open it in a new window and copy the URL.

5) Go to Uptime Robot again and paste the URL where it asks you to. Also, give it a 
   friendly name.

6) Select an email for Uptime Robot to notify

7) Lastly, click create monitor and you're good to go

Hope this helps!